# Can a benzyl ether be removed in the presence of an ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemoselectivity, protecting-groups

I'd like to deprotect a benzyl group for a [Fráter–Seebach alkylation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A1ter%E2%80%93Seebach_alkylation). Would it be possible to do this with a Birch reduction using Li/NH<sub>3</sub> (or Na/NH<sub>3</sub>), without also reducing the ester carbonyl group?

[image: Selective debenzylation of methyl (S)-3-(benzyloxy)butanoate]

If not, hydrogenation over Pd/C seems to be a plausible alternative. How else can I remove the benzyl group on oxygen?

Comment: Hydrogenolysis (H2, Pd/C) is by far the most common method. For a more comprehensive list, see the books by Greene and Wuts or Kocienski. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0470053488

Comment: Related: [Can an ether be selectively hydrolysed in the presence of an ester?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51112/16683)

Answer (score 2):

In Wutz's book on protecting groups,<sup>[1]</sup> I found an example of almost instantaneous reductive debenzylation which leaves an ester untouched:<sup>[2]</sup>

[image: Debenzylation example with Na/NH3]

The use of BCl<sub>3</sub> is also possible:<sup>[3]</sup>

[image: Debenzylation with BCl3]

---

**References:**

1. Wuts, P. G. M. *Greene's Protective Groups in Organic Synthesis*, 5th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2014, p 131.
2. Sulikowski, M. M.; Davies, G. E. R. E.; Smith, A. B., III. Avermectin–milbemycin synthetic studies. Part 7. An approach to the southern hemisphere of milbemycin α<sub>1</sub>. *J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. 1* **1992,** 979–989. [DOI: 10.1039/P19920000979](https://doi.org/10.1039/P19920000979).
3. Williams, D. R.; Brown, D. L.; Benbow, J. W. Studies of Stemona alkaloids. Total synthesis of (+)-croomine. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1989,** *111* (5), 1923–1925. [DOI: 10.1021/ja00187a081](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00187a081).